# perl variable scope using while loop

Tags: perl, while-loop, scope, subroutine

I have an ftp upload from my client machine to my server running consistently as a means of backup, occasionally if the connection becomes corrupt the upload will stall, the solution to this is to remove the "corrupt file" from the server, then the client resumes and the file is uploaded next time the client runs. This script is to remove the file if it has never occured before, or check the time stamp if it has been deleted in the past and check that this is a new occurence. Then delete if required.

the line in the logfile will be like:

```
Sun May 11 02:38:46 2010 [pid 17116] [ftp] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "192.168.179.58", "/Dan/Example.file", 0.00Kbyte/sec
```

and once written to the filelist it looks like this:

```
Sun May 11 02:38:46 - /Dan/Example.file
```

Below you can see where the scope problem lies within the `read_filelist()` sub-routine.

Please see the solution so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

#open /var/log/vsftpd.log read only, and /var/log/vsftpd.log R/W + append
open my $logfile, '<', '/var/log/vsftpd.log'  # 3 arg open is safer
    or die "could not open file: $!"; # checking for errors is good
open my $filelist, '+<', '/scripts/filelist' 
    or die "could not open file: $!";

my @rid;
my @filename;
my @deletedfile;
my $int = -1;
my @time;
my @hourcompare;
my @splittime;
my @filelisttime;
my @splitfilelisttime;
my @filelistfile;
my @filelistarray;
my $fileexists = 0;

#Define read_filelist()
sub read_filelist{

my ($filename, $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist) =  @_;

while (<$filelist>){
        @filelisttime = split /\s+/, $_;
        @splitfilelisttime = split /:/, $filelisttime[3];
        @filelistfile = split /\s+-\s+/, $_;
        my $fsec = $splitfilelisttime[2]+0;
        my $fmin = $splitfilelisttime[1]+0;
        my $fhour = $splitfilelisttime[0]+0;

    if ($filelistfile[2] eq $filename){
                my $fileexists = 1;
                       if ($hour >= $fhour){
                                if($min >= $fmin){
                                        if($sec > $fsec){
                                                system ("rm", "-fv", "/home/desktop"."$filename");
                                                        }
                                                 }
                                        }
                                }
    }
}

#open vsftp log and look for lines that include "FAIL UPLOAD" print those lines to a file
while (<$logfile>) {
$int = $int + 1;

    if (index($_, "FAIL UPLOAD:") != -1){
     @rid =  split /\s+"/, $_;
    @filename = split /",/, $rid[2];
    @time = split /\s+201/, $rid[0]; 
    }

$deletedfile[$int] = $filename[0];
        if ($filename[0] ne $deletedfile[$int-1]){
                print $filelist $time[0]." - ".$filename[0]."\n";
           }

#convert the timestamp into integers for comparison
@hourcompare = split /\s+/, $time[0];
@splittime = split /:/, $hourcompare[3];
my $sec = $splittime[2]+0;
my $min = $splittime[1]+0;
my $hour = $splittime[0]+0;

        #itterate through '/scripts/filelist'
    read_filelist($filename[0], $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist);

    if ($fileexists = 0){
        system ("rm", "-fv", "/home/desktop"."$filename[0]");
    }
}
close $filelist;
close $logfile;
```

the variables pass to the read_filelist() sub no problem, but when I start the while() loop all passed variables become uninitialized:

```
sub read_filelist {

    my ($filename, $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist) =  @_;

    while (<$filelist>) {

        @filelisttime = split /\s+/, $_;
        @splitfilelisttime = split /:/, $filelisttime[3];
        @filelistfile = split /\s+-\s+/, $_;
        my $fsec = $splitfilelisttime[2]+0;
        my $fmin = $splitfilelisttime[1]+0;
        my $fhour = $splitfilelisttime[0]+0;

        if ($filelistfile[2] eq $filename) {
            my $fileexists = "T";
            if ($hour >= $fhour) {
                if($min >= $fmin) {
                    if($sec > $fsec) {
                        system ("rm", "-fv", "/home/desktop"."$filename");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print "log: " . "$hour" . ":" . "$min" . ":" . "$sec" . "\n";
        print "file: " . "$fhour" . ":" . "$fmin" . ":" . "$fsec" . "\n";
        print "$filename" . "\n";
    }
}

read_filelist($filename[0], $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist);
```

This returns the following:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at removefailed.pl line 39, <$filelist> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $filename in string eq at removefailed.pl line 39, <$filelist> line 1.
log: 0:0:0
file: 2:38:46
Use of uninitialized value $filename in string at removefailed.pl line 52, <$filelist> line 1.
```

However if I move the prints outside of the while loop it works, but obviously I can only compare them with the last line of the filelist.

```
sub read_filelist {

    my ($filename, $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist) =  @_;
    print "log: " . "$hour" . ":" . "$min" . ":" . "$sec" . "\n";

    while (<$filelist>) {
        @filelisttime = split /\s+/, $_;
        @splitfilelisttime = split /:/, $filelisttime[3];
        @filelistfile = split /\s+-\s+/, $_;
        my $fsec = $splitfilelisttime[2]+0;
        my $fmin = $splitfilelisttime[1]+0;
        my $fhour = $splitfilelisttime[0]+0;

        if ($filelistfile[2] eq $filename) {
            my $fileexists = "T";
            if ($hour >= $fhour) {
                if($min >= $fmin) {
                    if($sec > $fsec) {
                        system ("rm", "-fv", "/home/desktop"."$filename");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print "file: " . "$fhour" . ":" . "$fmin" . ":" . "$fsec" . "\n";
    }
    print "$filename" . "\n";
}

read_filelist($filename[0], $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist);
```

I get the following output:

```
file: 2:38:46
log: 2:38:46
/Dan/Example.file
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated, please let me know if you need any further information?

Comment: Your solution is quite hard to read.  I suggest that you start with your original goal and sample data and describe that in detail first.

Comment: some sample data would be enormously helpful in figuring this out. the output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper \@_;` at the beginning of read_filelist, for instance

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I wil update this tomorrow with my original goal and provide the array dump.

Comment: `if($sec > $sec) ` is never going to be true.

Comment: Your shebang is wrong (although that's not the cause of the problem).

Comment: nice spot! :p updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using Hash's. I think this was caused because the filelist was already open in the logfile read.

Anyhow I created a global Hash:

```
my %logfilelines;
```

passed all the assorted relevant lines to it from the logfile:

```
$logfilelines{$filename[0].":".$hour.":".$min.":".$sec}++
```

Then within the read_file() sub I run through %logfilelines; and compare the filename\ time etc. I will have to rebuild the time comparison as it is wrong but atleast I am making progress now. see the new subroutine below in case you are curious:

```
sub read_filelist{

#my ($filename, $hour, $min, $sec, $filelist) =  @_;
my $fint = -1;
my @filelines;
my @filelistlines;

foreach my $line (keys %logfilelines) {
    open my $filelist2, '<', 'c:\scripts\filelist'
            or die "could not open file: $!";

    $fint = $fint + 1;
    $filelines[$fint] = $line;
    @filelistlines = split /:/, $filelines[$fint];
    my $filename = $filelistlines[0];
    my $hour = $filelistlines[1]+0;
    my $min = $filelistlines[2]+0;
    my $sec = $filelistlines[3]+0;

            while (<$filelist2>){

                my @filelisttime = split /\s+/, $_;
        my @splitfilelisttime = split /:/, $filelisttime[3];
        my @filelistfile = split /-\s+/, $_;
        my $fsec = $splitfilelisttime[2]+0;
        my $fmin = $splitfilelisttime[1]+0;
        my $fhour = $splitfilelisttime[0]+0;

                    chomp $filelistfile[1];

            if ($filelistfile[1] eq $filename){
                   # my $fileexists = 1;
                              print "log: "."$hour".":"."$min".":"."$sec"." $filename"."\n";
                              print "file: "."$fhour".":"."$fmin".":"."$fsec"."\n";
                           if ($min > $fmin || $hour > $fhour){
                            #        if($min >= $fmin ||$hour >= $fhour){
                          #                 if($sec > $fsec){
                                                    #system ("rm", "-fv", "/home/desktop"."$filename");
                                                                                                    print "success"." $filename";
                              #                             }
                                 #                   }
                                            }
                                    }

            }

    }
```